# Web API - Server-side processing (row formatting) of large data with datatable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, datatable

I have been using datatable very efficiently for a long time until I hit by a problem of loading large data into the table.
I am talking about 25K rows loading into datatable on client side. Firstly my web server used to crash due to lack of memory_limit assigned to handle the script (PHP).
Increasing the memory_limit fixed the crashing issue on the server-side, but now it takes enough time to load the data on the client side.
So I had decided to limit the data from the server itself using remote pagination.
That'why I have implemented the ajax processing to fetch the data. I works fine with simple data binding to the table.
But my problem is that I have a reasonable amount of conditions in the PHP code to hide and show control + coloring of the data.
All these are based on the user session and permission on Serverside which cannot be done on the javascript in drawCallback.

I am looking for a solution where I can fill the table rows in html format (after applying all the conditions with PHP code) to the datatable without losing the search, paging functionality.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Start a session and store the conditions there. Javascript will send any cookies along with AJAX calls, so you can get them from the session in subsequent calls.

Comment: How is **any help** an acceptable answer? In fact, how is this answerable without code? Read [ask]. Also ... `control + coloring of the data` ... `cannot be done on the javascript` is completely wrong. It ***can*** be done but you refuse to do so. In a proper system PHP doesn't have to deal with coloring as it should only process the data in a response. Also what does ASP have anything to do with it?